# Is there any sense in "feature request by design"?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently there are 57 questions tagged as [feature request + status-bydesign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+status-bydesign) (75 minus 14 where there is also [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag minus 4 that also have [support](/questions/tagged/support)).

Without looking into each of those I just think that logically speaking, feature request *can't really be by design*. It can be either rejected or accepted (completed).

What should be done about this? In my opinion most of those should be changed to status-completed or status-rejected instead of "bydesign" or other possible way to make it correct is changing the feature-request tag to "support" or "discussion".

Comment: I think you already know this, but [feature-request] [by-design] means *"The system already works the way it's intended to work, without the additional functionality your feature request would provide."*

Comment: Should be [status-declined] if the feature request is declined for whatever reason, including that of the feature being absent by design.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Or occasionally "with", when the functionality already exists. :)

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, this arrangement does seem a bit incongruous... A spot-check seems to indicate that most of these should be retagged in some way: either by changing the status to declined/completed, or by changing [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [support](/questions/tagged/support).

That said... Meh.

Comment: Yeah, I reluctantly throw "bydesign" on feature requests when the post obviously is a *feature request* for something that just happens to already exist. I suppose I could edit to make it a support question instead, but... meh.

Comment: Retag to status-completed to improve your KPI up the bronxzoo